# \newpage doesn't work between two tables

Tags: tables

I have this simple question to get two tables on two pages... any advises?
Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Number of observed years in the respective state of all candidates are counted for each model.}
\label{tab:table1}
\fbox{%
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
 & Correct Model & Healthy Candidate Bias & Time Dependent Bias\\
  &Winner/Runner-up& Winner/Runner-up& Winner/Runner-up\\\hline
Germany & 177/201 & 121/182 & 192/186\\
USA  & 214/271 & 182/259 & 222/263\\
UK  & 231/155 & 181/140 & 241/145\\\hline
Total  & 622/627 & 484/581 & 655/594\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\newpage


\begin{table}
\caption{Results of the death hazard ratio with the 95\% confidence interval (CI) for winners relative to runners-up of different cox models for the healthy candidate bias, time dependent bias and the correct model.}
\label{table2}
\fbox{%
\begin{tabular}{lccl}
   Cox-Model & Correct Model & Healthy Candidate Bias & Time Dependent Bias\\
\hline
Basic & 1.133 (0.568 - 2.260) & 1.302 (0.648 - 2.618) & 1.124 (0.563 - 2.244)\\
Strata(country) & 1.062 (0.488 - 2.311) & 1.293 (0.585 - 2.860) & 1.062 (0.488 - 2.311)\\
 \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`\newpage` doesn't really make much sense in that position. It is forcing a page break at a fixed point in the text float but the tables are floats so are taken out of the main text and re-positioned, so clearly the page break may not come between them.

Perhaps you intended `\clearpage` which flushes all pending floats so would force the first table to not float past that point. (Although giving it a `[t]` option so preventing it appear on a float page, then using `\clearpage` to force it on to a float page, is a bit odd.)

Comment: thx! it worked.